# jQuery - proper way to create plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to convert some of my code to reusable plugins.
Many times I'm filling selects with dynamic options that comes from Ajax request.

I've managed to create something like this:

```
$.fn.fillSelect = function fillSelect(options) {
var self = this;
options = $.extend({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Data.asmx/StatusList",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        var list = "";
        $.each(data.d, function(i) {
            list += '<option value='
                          + data.d[i].ID + '>'
                          + data.d[i].Nazwa
                          + '</option>';
        });
        self.filter("select").each(function() {
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).append(list);
            //use selectmenu
            if ($.ui.selectmenu) $(this).selectmenu();
        });
    }//,
    //error: function(result) {
    //    alert("Error loading data!");
    //}
}, options);
$.ajax(options);
return self;
}
```

Idea behind this is to be able to fill multiple selects with the same data multiple times with one request.
I have default options for Ajax request, but I would like to add some more options to it.
For example: 
clear - fill determinate if I want new options to replace existing ones or append.

Also I would like to add some callbacks to my function that I could pass as parameters.
If for example server request will fail I would like to specify a function that will be called after this error occurs - for example to show alert or disable my selects.

My question is how should I change my plugin or which pattern (boilerplate) I should use?

Every boilerplate I found is for creating plugins that will 'stay' inside selected item, so that it is possible to call method of that plugin later.

I need a simple plugin that will allow user to fill select and then it will end it's life :)

My main idea is to do only one request to server for all elements.

---

**Here is jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JC7vX/2/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my version of answer http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/ncWEw/

My plugin looks like this:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.ajaxSelect = function(options) {
    var $this = this;
    //options
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    //disable select
    if ($.ui.selectmenu && settings.selectmenu && settings.disableOnLoad) {
        $this.selectmenu('disable');
    }
    //ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: settings.type,
        contentType: settings.contentType,
        url: settings.url,
        dataType: settings.dataType,
        data: settings.data
    }).done(function(data) {
        var n = data.d || data;
        var list = "";
        $.each(n, function(i) {
            list += '<option value=' + n[i].Id + '>' + n[i].Nazwa + '</option>';
        });
        $this.filter("select").each(function() {
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).append(list);
            if ($.ui.selectmenu && settings.selectmenu) {
                $this.selectmenu();
            }
            settings.success.call(this);
        });
    }).fail(function() {
        settings.error.call(this);
    });

    return this;
};

var defaults = {
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '/echo/json/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: null,
    async: true,
    selectmenu: true,
    disableOnLoad: true,
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
};
})(jQuery);
```

I understand that it is very simple, but it has all functionality that I needed:
-You can select multiple elements at one time
-It filters only selects from Your selected items
-It makes only one request to server
-First it builds option string and then append it instead of adding items in loop
-You can specify 2 callbacks: one for error and second for success

And it is my first plugin, so there is much places for improvements.

As always comments and hints are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

A basic plugin can be built as follows

```
(function ($){
    $.fn.yourPlugin = function (options){
        // this ensures that function chaining can continue
        return this.each(function (){
            // merge defaults and user defined options
            var params = $.extend({},defaultOptions,options);
            // your plugin code
        });
    }

    /* these options will help define the standard functionality of the plugin,
     * and also serves as a nice reference
     */
    var defaultOptions = {
        someProperty : true
    }
})(jQuery)
```

There are other things that you can do to extend the functionality of your plugin and give public methods that retain the context, but that would be overkill for your example.

Comment: Thanks for response, but how can I plug Ajax call inside this. My first idea is inside this.each() but then Ajax call would be called every time for element.

Comment: additional code / jsfiddle would help, but you could call the plugin against the form and then using a user defined option add a class to the select elements that you want the plugin to run against. It would also be better define the success handler as a callback, it would make the plugin more reusable, arguably, if you don't allow the client code to pass a success handler, there is no point in making this a plugin.

Comment: then my previous comment is how I would go about it.

Comment: The success handler is defined inside my plugin, because what plugin should do is just add/replace options is selects. I could call it on only one select or on multiple ones. Using Your pattern I could add ajax call inside `return this.each(function() {/*here*/})' but as I wrote in my question I want I server call for all selects. I dont need to add my plugin to form, because I'm using selects without forms as everything is done via javascript. Just a simple one page app.